# How to use lfw dataset for face verification using CNN with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I would like to know how to assemble the dataset for facial verification, since I don't know how to do this using CNN. Using traditional machine learning techniques is easy, because you only need to extract the features of each image, convert the image pair into a concatenated vector and assign the labels, but how would it be to do this with CNN? Would I have to do the sum of the pair of images and pass it to the CNN network?

I haven't tried anything yet as I have no idea how to do this. If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the complete information on this problem from this [Document](https://www.atmosera.com/blog/facial-recognition-with-cnns/). Here is the [Working Notebook](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/drive/1Rn_ciRxjKjixRdH1M_N_-XtIpUi7wUf9#scrollTo=2IKmRiuhHM8E) for tryouts.

For going ahead with model building for the Facial Recognition with CNN for the LFW Dataset, please follow the following steps :

**1. Library Installation and Data Read-in**

Rudimentary data cleaning to ensure data is structured in intuitive data frames

**2. Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA)**

Data exploration, visualisations, and splitting the data into training/test/validation sets

**3. Evaluation Metric Decisions**

What is the most meaningful evaluation metric to use in this situation?

**4. Model Construction**

We discuss a number of candidate computer vision (CV) algorithms and assess the accuracy of CNN techniques on test data

**5. Results Analysis**

Discussion of results and their interpretations